# How to render a star rate component in react-native?

Tags: react-native, styles

How can i create the half colored star?

[image]

```
<Image source={require('../star.png')}
  style={{
    height: '100%',
    aspectRatio: 1,
    tintColor: 'blue',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
}} />
```

Is it possible to have a background View and use the Image as a mask?
I tried the following but it clearly fails.

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={{
      position: 'absolute',
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      width: '80%',
      height: '100%'
    }} />
    <Image source={require('../star.png')}
       style={{
         height: '100%',
         aspectRatio: 1,
         tintColor: 'transparent',
       }} />
 </View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this component to do this. but you should find a good image of a star which out of stars must be filled with a color and the background color of stars must be trasparent. I assume the width of each star 30 in this example. you should pass the rate value as a `prop`

```
export default class starRate extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{height: 30, width: 150}}>
        <View style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          backgroundColor: 'yellow',
          height: 30,
            width: this.props.rate*30,
        }} />
        <Image source={require('../star.png')}
           style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            height: 30,
            width: 150,
           }} />
     </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following accepted answer idea, i came up with a similar solution:

```
const colors = {background: 'white', color: 'yellow'};
const starIcon = require('../../img/star.png');

const Star = ({rating, inx, size, style} : {rating: number, inx: number, size: number, style: object}) => {
  const emptyIcon = {width: size, height: size, tintColor: colors.background};
  const fullIcon = {width: size, height: size, tintColor: colors.button};

  if(rating >= inx) { return (<Image source={starIcon} style={[ style, fullIcon ]} />); }
  if(rating <= inx-1) { return (<Image source={starIcon} style={[ style, emptyIcon ]} />); }

  const width = ((rating + 1 - inx) * size) | 0;

  return (
    <View style={style}>
      <Image source={starIcon} style={[emptyIcon]} />
      <View style={{ width: width, height: size, overflow: 'hidden', position: 'absolute'}}>
        <Image source={starIcon} style={[fullIcon]} />
      </View>
    </View>
 );
};

const StarsRating = ({rating} : {rating: number}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Star rating={rating} inx={1} size={20} style={styles.icon} />
      <Star rating={rating} inx={2} size={20} style={styles.icon} />
      <Star rating={rating} inx={3} size={20} style={styles.icon} />
      <Star rating={rating} inx={4} size={20} style={styles.icon} />
      <Star rating={rating} inx={5} size={20} style={styles.icon} />
    </View>
  )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  },
  icon: {
    marginLeft: 2,
  }
});
```